# Representing optional properties in a class

Tags: java

I have an Java class with a number of properties, some of which are optional.
In the example below the properties *linkerNumber*, *linkerStatus*, and *linkerPressure* are optional and represent a physical object that may or may not be attached to the device.

Right now I have mixed primitive and non-primitive types since *linkerPressure* is optional but *flow*, *inputPressure*, and *outputPressure* are required.

Should I:

- Change all properties to be non-primitive for the sake of uniformity?
- Mix primitive and non-primitive type to match what is/isn't required?
- Represent *linker* values as their own object with a special null class ([Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern))?

My aversion to using the Null Object Pattern is that a separate *linker* object would not provide any additional functionality to me.

```
public class State {
  private long serial;
  private long received;
  private String deviceId;
  private String linkerNumber;
  private String linkerStatus;
  private Integer linkerPressure;
  private int flow;
  private int inputPressure;
  private int outputPressure;
```

What is the best way to represent this data?

Comment: this is probably the only case where *optional* parameters should be wrapped around `Optional<T>`, even if `Optional<T>` is mostly used for return types

Comment: There is also `OptionalInt` etc. for primitive data types.

Comment: Do these values change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I* would first think of the Builder pattern (if that is not already in place here), then I would wrap each optional parameter into an `Optional` from `java.util` (or guava if you are under `java-8`).

Thing is, even if you make them all Objects, the caller of `getFlow` for example (that will return an `Integer`) would probably not think of checking for null *first* and then *acting* on it, it will assume a non-null value. How many times do you check the return types of Objects againt null?

But getting an `Optional<Integer>` (or `OptionalInt`) *forces* the caller to think and act accordingly. Just notice that `Optional<T>` is used mainly for return types, denoting a potentially missing value.

To stay in accordance to that you could have something like:

```
class State {
   private Integer flow; // nullable

   public Optional<Integer> getFlow(){
      return Optional.ofNullable(flow);
   }

}
```

Comment: I really like your example of using Objects and only using `Optional<T>` as the return type (like it was intended), thanks! **Should I use `Optional<T>` for all return types, even the types that should never be null (such as `flow`, `inputPressure`, and `outputPressure`)?**

Comment: @L.Inman well, no. that to me would be abusing `Optional`, you should return them as-is. Even better, validate them in the Builder via `Objects.requireNonNull` and fail fast